# How to handle XMLHttpRequests in a redux action?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I have a redux-form that is passing props to my action. The property this.props.userImages[0] is an image file from a file input on that form. I'm then taking that image and making and XMLHttpRequest to Cloudinary which generates a url for that image. Once I receive the url data (xhr.responseText), I'd like to then merge it with my other props to that I can then post all of my props to an API (all form info + newly created image URL).

I know that I have to wait for my request to generate a url to resolve, but having issues with getting it right before I can pass it onto my other function which can take that info and merge it in with props before posting to my API.

```
//..

function generateUrl(props) {

     // Grabs image file from my form's file input and uploads 
     // to cloudinary service so that a URL can be generated

  const cloudinaryURL = 'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/<my_name>/image/upload';
  const apiKey = 'secret_key';
  const uploadPreset = 'test_preset';

  const data = new FormData();
  data.append('file', props.userImages[0]);
  data.append('upload_preset', uploadPreset);
  data.append('api_key', apiKey);

  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', cloudinaryURL, true);
  xhr.send(data);
  xhr.onReadyStateChange = () => {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      return JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    }
  };

  return xhr.onReadyStateChange();
}

export function createReview(props) {

 const imageUrl = generateUrl(props);

 const mergedProps = //...

  // Here I'd like to merge my newly generated 
  // url back into props before I post to my API like so...

  const request = axios.post(`${REQUEST_URL}/api`, mergedProps)
  return {
    type: CREATE_REVIEW,
    payload: request
  }
};
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` is not and does not relate to promises. I don't understand the question in the context of promises.

Comment: When I send my form data, I believe I have to wait for my XMLHttpRequest to return a responseText if the ready state is 4 and status is 200 so I feel like I can't immediately return this since it has to wait to receive the ready state and status. Let me know if that's correct or not. Thanks!

Comment: It is correct but that has nothing to do with promises. Also it doesn't _return_ anything you have to use the XHR callbacks.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've updated the title to reflect that this doesn't concern promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with promises in the context of your example `XMLHttpRequest` based code.

The assumption your making is that the callback assigned to `onReadyStateChange` does something with it's return value. Instead anything returned from that function is dutifully ignored.

What you want is to pass the value onward through another callback.

```
function generateUrl(props, callback) {
  // Do things here
    xhr.onReadyStateChange = () => {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        callback(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
      }
    };
}


generateUrl(props, (response) => {
  const mergedProps = // Use response as expected.
});
```

Since you mentioned promise and your using ES2015 we can convert this to actually use promises which is probably what you wanted to begin with.

```
function generateUrl(props) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const cloudinaryURL = 'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/<my_name>/image/upload';
    const apiKey = 'secret_key';
    const uploadPreset = 'test_preset';

    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', props.userImages[0]);
    data.append('upload_preset', uploadPreset);
    data.append('api_key', apiKey);

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onReadyStateChange = () => {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
          resolve(xhr.responseText);
        } else {
          reject(new Error(`Failed HTTP request (${xhr.status})`));
        }
    };
    xhr.onerror = reject;

    xhr.open('POST', cloudinaryURL, true);
    xhr.send(data);
  });
}

generateUrl(props)
  .then(JSON.parse)
  .then(results => {
    // Do something with response
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Do something with the error
  });
```